# How do you execute Data Synchronizations between EPMA applications programmatically?

Tags: oracle, data-synchronization, hyperion

I would like to schedule a batch job in which a can execute a move of data between two workspace application in Hyperion Fusion Edition for Oracle. The tool provided is called 'Data Synchronization' This tool allows for this type if activity to occur upon request via the workspace environment.

- How might I do this automatically?

I noticed there is a Batch Scheduler for which I can request command line batch file to run at a pre-specified time. However, I do not know what resources are available to show me how to do this for the Data-Synchronizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch script can be created according to the rules outlined in the following user guide document at [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/epma_batch_user.pdf).

Please note the command class to accomplish this is the DIMSYNCHRONIZATION class.

The following is an example used in the guide:

```
 execute datasynchronization
 parameters(DataSynchronizationName, _
            DataTransformationOperator, _
            DataTransformationValue, _
            FileName, _
            UploadFile, _
            ValidateOnly, _
            WaitForCompletion)
 values('CommaSync3', _
        '*', _
        '1.2345', _
        '', _
        'false', _
        'false', _
        'true');
```

**DataSynchronizationName** must be a valid name of your pre-created Data Synchronization
This can be created through workspace using:

```
 Navigation Button --> Administer --> Data Synchronization
```

**DataTransformationOperator** Can be '' to ensure no transformation occurs on the data
This would typically be used if the source application is in a different precision than the destination application; such as in thousands. On transfer you have the opportunity to adjust the values accordingly to match the source and destination applications.

**DataTransformationValue** Can be '' to ensure no transformation occurs.

**FileName** and **UploadFile** can be '' to ensure the source of the synchronization is not a file.

**ValidateOnly** can be true or false depending on if you want to only validate the data synchronization or execute it. (True for Validate False for Execute)

**WaitForCompletion** can be true or false depending on if you want the code to wait for process to complete before going onto the next item in the batch script. (True for Wait, False for starting thread and continuing onto the next item)